# Binding a URL to custom SVG container's BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have been using the code layout [here](http://www.pshul.com/2018/01/25/xamarin-forms-using-svg-images-with-skiasharp/) to create an SVG container for a Xamarin Forms project. It works well and I reconfigured it to read the image from a remote URL.

The `ResourceId` is from the source above:

```cs
        public static readonly BindableProperty SvgUriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            "ResourceId",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(SvgUriContainer),
            default(string),
            propertyChanged: RedrawCanvas);


        public string ResourceId
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(SvgUriProperty);
            set => SetValue(SvgUriProperty, value);
        }
```

However I can not seem to bind that URL at run time in the XAML:

```xml
    <control:SvgUriContainer 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="4"
        Grid.Column="0"
        ResourceId="{Binding StampUri}" 
        [...]
    />
```

That Binding returns a string and the rest of the bindings work fine. Any attempt to bind in that fashion results in a build error:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ResourceId', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

No matter what I do in the container logic with the `BindableProperty`creation, the  error is the same and is in the XAML. Am I getting the syntax wrong in the XAML? Is it because `Binding` is a `BindingExtension` (not a string) at build time?

Note: if I replace the Binding with a string/URL it all works fine.

Note: if I set the type of `ResourceId` to `object` I can get by the build error but the string does not resolve, of course.

Comment: sharing the code for the ResourceID property would be helpful

Comment: Edited. Should have included it.

Comment: So nice to see that my blog post is actually helping out someone! :)
The code that you've shared looks fine to me and even compiles on my end.
Can you share some more code? e.g. Your view model, the control (if you made any changes) or the xaml itself?

Comment: @AlexPshul cool - yes, great blog post! I can not really share the code, however I have built a project on the side to isolate the code. I will try to reproduce tonight and share the source.

Comment: @AlexPshul I _was_ able to get it to work correctly in a much simpler project. For grins and for anyone interested I pushed it [here](https://github.com/Omortis/SvgFxRemote). Basically a slightly modified clone of your SvgFx code. I will have to refactor my code a bit to get the binding to work...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to modify your bindableProperty to the standard format described in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#creating-a-property):

```
  public static readonly BindableProperty SvgUriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      "SvgUri",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(EventToCommandBehavior),
      "test",
      propertyChanged: RedrawCanvas);


    public string SvgUri
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SvgUriProperty);
        set => SetValue(SvgUriProperty, value);
    }
```

Xamarin requires a Property naming convention.

Comment: Tried that, though my binding issue lies elsewhere. Thanks for the naming convention pointer, though!

Comment: If you can share your project, I can test it for you.